# AWS .NET SDK: creating an AmazonS3Client without using the access/secrete key?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I know how to access S3 using the access/secrete keys:

```
string accessKey = "my access key"; 
string secretKey = "my secrete key"; 
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
ListBucketsResponse response = client.ListBuckets();
```

However, this means storing the keys inside the code. This code runs on an EC2 instance, to which I have assigned the **S3 full admin** IAM role. I could open a CMD window and enter "**aws s3 ls**" and it worked. But if I pass NULL to the two keys in the above code, it will throw the following error:

```
Invalid S3 URI - hostname does not appear to be a valid S3 endpoint
```

So, how to run the above code, on an EC2 instance which has been assigned the **S3 full admin** IAM role, without hard-coding the access keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the sample about half way down here -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-hosm.html

You'll see that you don't pass anything to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor that does not take accessKey and secret as parameters:

```
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
ListBucketsResponse response = client.ListBuckets();
```

By omitting them completely, the SDK will access the role for them.